# What is the best way to return a list from an Async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writing an RSS reader using this example https://github.com/dotnet/SyndicationFeedReaderWriter

I want to record all `ISyndicationItem`'s to return as a list. The compiler error I'm getting is "Error CS1983  The return type of an `async` method must be `void`, `Task`, `Task<T>`, a task-like type, `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, or `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`" What is the most ideal way to do this?

```
using Microsoft.SyndicationFeed;
using Microsoft.SyndicationFeed.Rss;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

static async List<ISyndicationItem> ReadRSSFeed(string inputUri)
{
    var itemList = new List<ISyndicationItem>();
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(inputUri,
        new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
    {
        var feedReader = new RssFeedReader(xmlReader);

        while (await feedReader.Read())
        {
            switch (feedReader.ElementType)
            {
                // Read category
                case SyndicationElementType.Category:
                    ISyndicationCategory category = await feedReader.ReadCategory();
                    break;

                // Read Image
                case SyndicationElementType.Image:
                    ISyndicationImage image = await feedReader.ReadImage();
                    break;

                // Read Item
                case SyndicationElementType.Item:
                    ISyndicationItem item = await feedReader.ReadItem();
                    itemList.Add(item);
                    break;

                // Read link
                case SyndicationElementType.Link:
                    ISyndicationLink link = await feedReader.ReadLink();
                    break;

                // Read Person
                case SyndicationElementType.Person:
                    ISyndicationPerson person = await feedReader.ReadPerson();
                    break;

                // Read content
                default:
                    ISyndicationContent content = await feedReader.ReadContent();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return `Task<T>` instead of `T`.  Inside the method you still return an instance of `T`.

So should be:

```
static async Task<List<ISyndicationItem>> ReadRSSFeed(string inputUri)
```

Comment: Another possible option is to return `IAsyncEnumerable<ISyndicationItem>` in order to retutn `ISyndicationItem` one after one, and not wait the until entire list is crated.